# How to pull JSON values when there are multiple same values

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to pull out from this JSON column - "toTimestamp" & "fromTimestamp" so I can calculate instances when the video is above a certain number of seconds.  (Postgresql)

*Metadata column

```
"videoMetadata": [
   {
      "cameraId":"74",
      "toTimestamp":"2023-02-15T13:06:43.050Z",
      "fromTimestamp":"2023-02-15T13:06:39.050Z"
   },
   {
      "cameraId":"236",
      "toTimestamp":"2023-02-15T13:06:43.050Z",
      "fromTimestamp":"2023-02-15T13:06:39.050Z"
   },
   {
      "cameraId":"12",
      "toTimestamp":"2023-02-15T13:06:43.050Z",
      "fromTimestamp":"2023-02-15T13:06:39.050Z"
   },
   {
      "cameraId":"8",
      "toTimestamp":"2023-02-15T13:06:43.050Z",
      "fromTimestamp":"2023-02-15T13:06:39.050Z"
   }
],
```

I tried to use metadata->'videoMetadata'->>'toTimestamp' as XXX
But I get null values only and I suspect it is because the 'toTimestamp' is presented more than once.

Comment: Well, `videoMetadata` is an array. Which array element do want? Or do you want one row for each array element?

Comment: I need the toTimestamp and fromTimestamp, no matter from which 'cameraId' as they all the same value.

what I did was:
SELECT metadata->'videoMetadata'->'toTimestamp' as start, metadata->'videoMetadata'->'fromTimestamp' as end
From test

Answer (score 0):

`videoMetadata` is an array, so you need to specify from which array element you want to take the timestamps. If you don't care which one you get, just take the first:

```
SELECT metadata -> 'videoMetadata' -> 0 ->> 'toTimestamp' as start, 
       metadata -> 'videoMetadata' -> 0 ->> 'fromTimestamp' as end 
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select (jsonb_array_elements(json_row->'videoMetadata'))->>'cameraId' as cameraId,
       (jsonb_array_elements(json_row->'videoMetadata'))->>'toTimestamp'  as toTimestamp,
       (jsonb_array_elements(json_row->'videoMetadata'))->>'fromTimestamp' as fromTimestamp
 from table_Name
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1pfIt5uz)